# WPF - Why are buttons resizing after busy indicator goes away?

Tags: c#, wpf

When the busy indicator is visible the buttons resize to a wider width and when the indicator goes away it resizes back down to expected width. I thought using span attribute would fix this but it didn't.

```
<Window x:Class="TelerikWpfApp3.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="LogonBusyIndicator" IsBusy="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" Padding="10"  />
                <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" Padding="10" Click="button2_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: why are you setting `Grid.Column` on buttons that are in a `StackPanel`?

Comment: I'm a WPF noob?

Comment: you should probably just move the buttons outside of the `telerik:RadBusyIndicator`. they should be in the grid.

Comment: But what if I don't want them clicked before busy indicator?

Comment: Then disable them. and even if you don't the indicator will still be over the buttons

Answer (score 0):

What action causes the busy indicator to disappear?  Are you programmatically setting IsBusy to False in code-behind once login is ready?  If you don't want Button1 and Button2 to be clicked before the busy indicator closes, you can always do a trigger like this.

```
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" Padding="10"  />
                <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" Padding="10" Click="button2_Click"/>
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy, ElementName=LogonBusyIndicator}" Value="False">
                               <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True" />
                           </DataTrigger> 
                       </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
            </StackPanel>
            <telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="LogonBusyIndicator" IsBusy="True"/>
```

Here's what's happening with the code above.

- First and foremost, by removing the buttons entirely from the telerik RadBusyIndicator xaml definition, the buttons size will remain their original size and not get resized whenever the busy indicator turns off or on.  I think by placing these buttons inside of the RadBusyIndicator, you have put a reliance on how that telerik control sizes itself.  Now there should be no dependency.
- The busy indicator will ALWAYS be placed above the buttons in the visual tree z-order, because I defined it last.
- To prevent the user from clicking the buttons until the busy indicator is ready, I have set the IsHitTestVisible to false by default.  This means that anything in the StackPanel cannot be clicked.
- But then I set up a trigger to say, when the busy indicator's "IsBusy" property gets set to False (programmatically?), then set the StackPanel's IsHitTestVisible property to True so that the user can now click these buttons.

Comment: I'm setting it in the code behind manually for testing purposes. How is this normally done?

Comment: Setting the IsBusy property to False in code-behind manually is perfectly normal.  You're doing fine.  It's just hard to help figure out what's wrong unless you post both the xaml and xaml.cs.  Just a friendly reminder for you to do this next time, so that it let's us see for ourselves, instead of guessing what might be the problem.  Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Content` of the `RadBusyIndicator` to the `Grid` with the buttons:

```
<telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="LogonBusyIndicator" IsBusy="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" Padding="10"  />
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" Padding="10" Click="button2_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
```